# Somebody who comes up with an idea, but needs somebody else to create something from that idea

Tags: nouns

Here's the situation:

Ideas come in two parts: seed and finalized.

Some people can create many seed ideas but can't finish them.

Some people can't create seed ideas, but can source seeds from others and create a final product.

Example: in Cujo, Tadder's dad is part of an advertising duo. He creates the seed idea, while his partner creates the actual advert based on the seed idea.

I keep wanting to call this Part 1 Ideist (eye-dee-ist) and Part 2 Ideist, but the internet says ideist is a synonym of idealist, which is someone who aims for perfection. Is there a word that means a person who creates ideas?

Comment: Thank you, @SomethingDark for the corrected title! I had a really hard time figuring out how to word all of this.

Answer (score 2):

conceptualist

"A conceptualist would be a great job for firms. A person who looks at various problems in a firm /business and comes up with workable ideas to solve those problems."

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conceptualist

Conceptualist and conceptualizer would both be appropriate. Choice of term would be subjective. In the rhythm of today's language, I prefer conceptualist, since the ending is similar to artist, and conceptualist sounds more artistic, whereas conceptualizer sounds to me like a machine, like synthesizer.

To explain: "conceptualist:an adherent to the tenets of conceptualism or of conceptual art"
conceptualism: " conceptual art" : "an art form in which the artist's intent is to convey a concept rather than to create an art object"

"An artist involved in the conceptualism movement."

http://www.yourdictionary.com/conceptualist#wiktionary

"An artist is defined as a person who creates ...pieces of writing,...or a variety of other types of creative products...
a person who does anything very well, with imagination"

http://www.yourdictionary.com/artist

Comment: I think you mean a conceptualizer; a conceptualist (according to your link) is a person who believes that [universals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_(metaphysics)) exist only in your mind.

Comment: @SomethingDark See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! It's a very long, difficult for me to pronounce word (i keep saying conceptionist), but it is a legitimate word, which is better than i had before.

Comment: @JaqueValentine It's five syllables. Think of longer words that you know, like environmentalist, with six syllables, and take heart.

Answer (score 1):

Person 1 would be a designer.

> [designer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/designer) (n.) - A person who plans the look or workings of something prior to it being made, by preparing drawings or plans

Person 1 could also be considered a muse for person 2.

> [muse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/muse) (n.) - A person or personified force who is the source of inspiration for a creative artist